# SAS code is giving error for Do-While loop

Tags: loops, sas

I need to print the fuel consumption and mileage of the car in SAS code. if given that mileage is 20 miles per gallon. 
It should stop generating output if fuel reaches to 10  gallon **OR** car travel 250 miles. 
My code:

```
data milage;
fuel=1;
do while (fuel<11);
miles =  fuel*20;
fuel+1;
output;
end;
run;
```

My output:

[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taRft.png)

The output for fuel needs to be started from 1  for first 20 miles which incorrect in my code. Any suggestion on what I am missing here.

Thanks!!

Comment: try switching `fuel+1` and `output` statements. You need to output the first `fuel` if you want it to start at 1. BTW, your title suggests that your Do-While loop throws an error. What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an explicit OUTPUT for the first line or start at 0 instead. If
   you start at 0, make sure the order of the fuel and miles
   calculation are correct.
2. Change your loop condition to be <10 and add in the MILES criteria
   as well. In this case you're only looping if fuel<10 AND the miles
   lt 250. Make sure the boundaries are what you want.

   ```
   data milage;
   fuel=0; miles=0;

   do while (fuel<10 and miles lt 250);

       fuel+1;
       miles =  fuel*20;

       output;
   end;

   run;
   ```